# How to efficiently get a list like this?

Tags: list-manipulation, expression-construction

I want a function `myfun` that generates list like this

```
myfun[1]
{{1}}

myfun[2]
{{0, 1}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {1, 2}}

myfun[3]
{{0, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 1}, {0, 1, 2}, {1, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 2}, {1, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 2}, {1, 2, 0}}

myfun[4]
{{0, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 1, 2}, {0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 0, 2}, {0, 1, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 1, 1}, {0, 1, 1, 2}, {0, 1, 2, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 0, 2}, {1, 0, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 1, 1}, {1, 0, 1, 2}, {1, 0, 2, 0}, {1, 1, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 0, 2}, {1, 1, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 2}, {1, 1, 2, 0}, {1, 2, 0, 0}}

myfun[5]
{{0, 0, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 1, 2}, {0, 0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 1, 0, 2}, {0, 0, 1, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 1, 1, 2}, {0, 0, 1, 2, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 0, 0, 2}, {0, 1, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 1, 1}, {0, 1, 0, 1, 2}, {0, 1, 0, 2, 0}, {0, 1, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 1, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 1, 0, 2}, {0, 1, 1, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {0, 1, 1, 1, 2}, {0, 1, 1, 2, 0}, {0, 1, 2, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 0, 0, 2}, {1, 0, 0, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 1, 1}, {1, 0, 0, 1, 2}, {1, 0, 0, 2, 0}, {1, 0, 1, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 1, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 1, 0, 2}, {1, 0, 1, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 0, 1, 1, 2}, {1, 0, 1, 2, 0}, {1, 0, 2, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 0, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 0, 0, 2}, {1, 1, 0, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 0, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 0, 1, 2}, {1, 1, 0, 2, 0}, {1, 1, 1, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 1, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 0, 2}, {1, 1, 1, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 1, 2}, {1, 1, 1, 2, 0}, {1, 1, 2, 0, 0}, {1, 2, 0, 0, 0}}
```

**Feature of the list:**
Each element is of length `K`.
Only 0,1,2 are allowed.
Must have at least a 1.
Can have 0s,1s only, without a 2.
If 2 exists, must be after at least a 1 AND after any 2, there must be 0 (or 0s or nothing).

The length of the list is determined by

```
nLength[K_Integer] := LinearRecurrence[{4, -5, 2}, {1, 4, 11}, K][[K]];
```

So the length of the first 8 lists are {1,4,11,26,57,120,247,502} and so on.

Some pieces I have got:

```
mytest[K_] := Drop[Flatten[{Tuples[{0, 1}, K], ReplaceList[ConstantArray[0, K], {a___, x_, b___, y_, c___} :> {a, 1, b, 2, c}]}, 1], 1];
```

It only works for the first two lists. And there are pieces missing (obviously). How can I create this effectively for large `K`, like 20,30? We will get length of list equal to 2097130 and 2147483616.

Comment: Can you explain what elements the list should contain?  It looks like you want all lists of length `K` consisting of the numbers 0, 1, and 2, such that only zeros can follow a 2, and each list must contain at least one 1; is this correct?

Comment: @2012rcampion I should have mentioned this! Yes, that's pretty much it. Please see updated post.

Comment: The list of only zeros fulfills your criteria, but is not included?

Comment: No, that is not of interest. But if that's included, I can drop it easily once the list is sorted.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why these particular features ? Also, any ref. for the linear recurrence ? Thanks.

Comment: @SquareOne These are the capture histories for a statistical model, called capture recapture recovery,see http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1572312712000809 .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
myFunction[n_Integer /; n >= 0] := 
 Sort[Join @@ 
   Table[If[k == 0, 
      Identity, #~Join~{2}~Join~ConstantArray[0, k - 1] &] /@ 
     Rest[Tuples[{0, 1}, n - k]], {k, 0, n - 1}]]
```

- Since the list must end with a `2` followed by `0`s, we start by enumerating the number of `2`s and `0`s that can follow (`k`, from no `0`s to all but one--since the list must contain at least one `1`).
- We generate the first part of the list containing `0`s and `1`s using `Tuple`.  We `Drop` the first element since it contains no `1`s (although not specified, this is implied by the examples).
- Then, we append a `2` and the correct number of `0`s using `Join` to the list (unless `k` is zero, in which case we don't append anything and pass the list unaltered with `Identity`).
- Finally we `Join` all the individual `k`-case lists together and `Sort` the result to match the specified output.

Comment: `myFunction[20]; // AbsoluteTiming` takes about 2 seconds, which is amazing. But `myFunction[30];` has MemoryAllocationFailure. Do you have any idea how much memory I would have to have? I only got 4G RAM.

Comment: Note that although the case for 20 only takes 1.5 seconds on my machine, by 23 it takes 14.6 seconds and by 24 my computer runs out of physical memory (and I have 16 gigs of it!).

Comment: That's fair enough. I should try to find a machine with much more RAM. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I was writing that comment when you posted yours and didn't see it... Using `RSolve` to find a closed-form expression for your linear recurrence, we see that the length of list `n` is $2^{n+1}-2-n$, growing exponentially.  Every time you double your RAM you are only increasing $n$ by one.  Case 30 would require roughly 1000 times more memory, so you would be far into the range of clusters or supercomputers.  What is this list for?

Comment: Just a programming note, you probably should avoid using `K` as your index, since Mathematica already has it defined as `a default generic name for a summation index in a symbolic sum.`  (See `K // FullDefinition`).  In general, you should use variable names with a lowercase first letter (`k` and `myFunction`) since all of Mathematica's built-in definitions are capitalized (`Solve` and `FindFirst`).

Comment: It might be surprise to you but I just needed K=30 for *fun*. I only need for K up to about 10,12. I got a bit bored writing my PhD thesis. So just having fun testing some really large values. The lists are something we call histories for capture recapture recovery data. http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1572312712000809

Comment: Very nicely done. +1

Answer (score 2):

I am quite out of practice (and apologies if I have misinterpreted):

```
fun[n_] := 
 With[{tu = Tuples[{0, 1, 2}, n]}, 
  Union[Cases[tu, {___?(# != 2 &), 1, ___?(# != 2 &)}], 
   Cases[tu, {___?(# != 2 &), 1, ___?(# != 2 &), 2, 
      0 ..} | {___?(# != 2 &), 1, ___?(# != 2 &), 2}]]]
```

Testing:

```
Grid[{#, Length@#} & /@ (fun /@ Range[5]), Frame -> All]
```

yields:

[image]

and

```
Length /@ (fun /@ Range[10])
```

yields: {1, 4, 11, 26, 57, 120, 247, 502, 1013, 2036}

Comment: You code run fine and there is no misinterpretation at all. However, @2012rcampion 's answer does run much faster and much less memory than yours.